# Nested Associations with FactoryBot

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I am developing an app for internal use and am using rspec and factorybot for testing.

There are 6 tables related to a user and I am having a problem building the factories

```
District  
Building  
Role  
DistrictRole (district_id, role_id, user_id)  
BuildingRole (building_id, role_id, user_id)  
User
```

A user must be in at least one district and one building to be valid
DistrictRole must have a valid district_id, role_id, and user_id
BuildingRole must have a valid building_id, role_id, and user_id

I've have found nothing online explaining how to do the associations and whether to build or create.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the `factory_bot` [documentation](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/factory_bot/file/GETTING_STARTED.md#Associations) on associations?

> A user must be in at least one district and one building to be valid
>
> DistrictRole must have a valid district_id, role_id, and user_id
>
> BuildingRole must have a valid building_id, role_id, and user_id

This is a chicken and the egg problem, which comes first? The user or the district & building?

In general, it's okay to validate association presence from the `belongs_to` end of the association. Going the reversed direction of requiring a model have X associated records can be a code smell, making things are to build and maintain (but not impossible). If you have these types of data structure requirements, I suggest you hand them outside of the model.

Comment: That's just what I was thinking...  If I don't have the validation in the model it wouldn't be an issue...  :-)